# Dart using abstract classes as interface: an meaningful design example

Tags: dart

I tried to find a useful example of using abstract classes as interface in Dart, but without success. In some examples, the abstract classes have instance variables as well as implemented methods, which has no sense for Dart interfaces. And I did not find an example demonstrating how using interfaces in Dart is very useful at the design level. For this reason, I do share the following code.

The idea is to define several interfaces in order for different part of the code to be restricted to using only the methods defined in the interface through which it obtained the Adult instance, Adult instances which do implement all the interfaces.

```
abstract class HumanInterface {
  // THE COMMENTED CODE HAS NO UTILITY IN A PURE ABSTRACT INTERFACE CLASS !
  //String _name;
  //HumanInterface(String name) : _name = name;

  String get name;
}

abstract class ParentInterface {
  void incrementChildNumber();
  int get childNumber;
}

abstract class EmployeeInterface implements HumanInterface {
  // extends can be used in place of implements !
  set salary(double salary);
  double get salary;
}

class Adult implements EmployeeInterface, ParentInterface {
  final String _name; // from HumanInterface implemented by EmployeeInterface
  double _salary; // from EmployeeInterface
  int _childNumber = 0; // from ParentInterface

  Adult(String name, double salary)
      : _name = name,
        _salary = salary;

  String get name => _name;

  double get salary => _salary;
  set salary(double salary) => _salary = salary;

  void incrementChildNumber() => _childNumber++;
  int get childNumber => _childNumber;
}

class MyFriends {
  /// Uses Adult as HumanInterface only
  List<HumanInterface> _friendLst = [];

  void addFriend(HumanInterface friend) => _friendLst.add(friend);
  void printMyFriends() {
    String toPrint = 'My friends:';

    for (HumanInterface friend in _friendLst) {
      toPrint += ' ${friend.name}';
    }

    print(toPrint);
  }
}

class Enterprise {
  /// Uses Adult as EmployeeInterface only
  List<EmployeeInterface> _employeeLst;

  Enterprise() : _employeeLst = [];

  void addEmployee(EmployeeInterface employee) => _employeeLst.add(employee);
  void printMonthlyTotalSalary() {
    double _totalSalary = 0;

    for (EmployeeInterface employee in _employeeLst) {
      _totalSalary += employee.salary;
    }

    print('Paying monthly: $_totalSalary');
  }

  void printEmployees() {
    String toPrint = 'Our employees:';

    for (EmployeeInterface employee in _employeeLst) {
      toPrint += ' ${employee.name} ${employee.salary}';
    }

    print(toPrint);
  }
}

class RemarriedCouple {
  /// Uses Adult as ParentInterface only
  ParentInterface _husband;
  ParentInterface _spouse;

  RemarriedCouple(ParentInterface husband, ParentInterface spouse)
      : _husband = husband,
        _spouse = spouse;

  int getChildrenNumber() => _husband.childNumber + _spouse.childNumber;
}

void main() {
  Adult adult = Adult('Joe', 10000);
  adult.incrementChildNumber();
  print('${adult.name} ${adult.salary} ${adult.childNumber}'); // Joe 10000.0 1

  EmployeeInterface employee = adult;
  print(employee.salary); // 10000.0
  print(employee.name); // Joe
//print(employee.childNumber); // compile error: The getter 'childNumber'
//                                isn't defined for the type 'EmployeeInterface'

  HumanInterface human = adult;
  print(human.name); // Joe
//print(human.salary); // compile error: The getter 'salary' isn't defined
//                        for the type 'HumanInterface'

  Adult adult2 = Adult('Carla', 11000);
  adult2.incrementChildNumber();
  adult2.incrementChildNumber();

  MyFriends myFriends = MyFriends();
  myFriends.addFriend(adult);
  myFriends.addFriend(adult2);
  myFriends.printMyFriends(); // My friends: Joe Carla

  Enterprise enterprise = Enterprise();
  enterprise.addEmployee(adult);
  enterprise.addEmployee(adult2);
  enterprise.printEmployees(); // Our employees Joe 10000.0 Carla 11000.0
  enterprise.printMonthlyTotalSalary(); // Paying monthly: 21000.0

  RemarriedCouple couple = RemarriedCouple(adult, adult2);
  print('Child number: ${couple.getChildrenNumber()}'); // Child number: 3
}
```

Comment: What is your question?  Statements such as `EmployeeInterface employee = adult;` and `HumanInterface human = adult;` are pointless (and counterproductive), and you wouldn't actually do that in practice.

Comment: Your question reads like "what is an interface good for?" Do you have questions about the general construct typically called "interface" in other languages, or the specifics of the Dart language not having the keyword and instead using abstract classes for the same effect?